# Using SKS file as overlay for background image for iOS?

Tags: ios, image, background, overlay

I am currently building a Christmas app. I've found I can use the particle builder to create a real nice snow falling effect that I'd like to use for my background. The app is a tabbed-view app. Is it possible to use the SKS file as an overlay onto the background image?